# multiline parser is not working in k8s env

Tags: fluent-bit

here I am using fluentbit to send pods logs into cloudwatch but it inserting every message as single log instead of that how i can push multiple logs into single message. pF below image
[image]

below is my updated configmap which i have tried by adding parser cri and filter as multiline but didnt work

i was using image : amazon/aws-for-fluent-bit:2.29.0

```
# Source: fluent-bit/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: fluent-bit
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: fluent-bit-compatible
data:
  fluent-bit.conf: |

    [SERVICE]
        Flush         2
        Log_Level     info
        Daemon        Off
        Parsers_File  parsers.conf
        Parsers_File  custom_parsers.conf
        HTTP_Server   On
        HTTP_Listen   0.0.0.0
        HTTP_Port     2020

    [INPUT]
        Name                tail
        Tag                 application.*
        Exclude_Path        /var/log/containers/cloudwatch-agent*, /var/log/containers/fluent-bit*, /var/log/containers/aws-node*, /var/log/containers/kube-proxy*
        Path                /var/log/containers/*.log
        Docker_Mode         On
        Docker_Mode_Flush   5
        Docker_Mode_Parser  container_firstline
        Parser              docker
        DB                  /var/fluent-bit/state/flb_container.db
        Mem_Buf_Limit       50MB
        Skip_Long_Lines     On
        Refresh_Interval    10
        Rotate_Wait         30
        Read_from_Head      Off

    [INPUT]
        Name                tail
        Tag                 application.*
        Path                /var/log/containers/fluent-bit*
        Parser              docker
        DB                  /var/fluent-bit/state/flb_log.db
        Mem_Buf_Limit       5MB
        Skip_Long_Lines     On
        Refresh_Interval    10
        Read_from_Head      Off

    [INPUT]
        Name                tail
        Tag                 application.*
        Path                /var/log/containers/cloudwatch-agent*
        Multiline.parser    docker,cri
        # Docker_Mode         On
        # Docker_Mode_Flush   5
        # Docker_Mode_Parser  cwagent_firstline
        #Parser              docker
        DB                  /var/fluent-bit/state/flb_cwagent.db
        rotate_wait         15
        Mem_Buf_Limit       5MB
        Skip_Long_Lines     On
        Refresh_Interval    10
        #Read_from_Head      true   

    [FILTER]
        Name                kubernetes
        Match               application.*
        Kube_URL            https://kubernetes.default.svc:443
        Kube_CA_File        /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        Kube_Token_File     /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
        Kube_Tag_Prefix     application.var.log.containers.
        Merge_Log           On
        Merge_Log_Key       log_processed
        K8S-Logging.Parser  On
        K8S-Logging.Exclude Off
        Labels              Off
        Annotations         Off
    
    [FILTER]
        Name               multiline
        Match              application.*
        multiline.key_content log
        multiline.parser   docker, cri

    [OUTPUT]
        Name                cloudwatch_logs
        Match               application.*
        region              ${REGION}
        log_group_name      /aws/containerinsights/${CLUSTER_NAME}/application
        log_stream_prefix   ${APP_POD_NAMESPACE}-
        auto_create_group   true
        extra_user_agent    container-insights

    [INPUT]
        Name                systemd
        Tag                 dataplane.systemd.*
        Systemd_Filter      _SYSTEMD_UNIT=docker.service
        Systemd_Filter      _SYSTEMD_UNIT=kubelet.service
        DB                  /var/fluent-bit/state/systemd.db
        Path                /var/log/journal
        Read_From_Tail      Off

    [INPUT]
        Name                tail
        Tag                 dataplane.tail.*
        Path                /var/log/containers/aws-node*, /var/log/containers/kube-proxy*
        Docker_Mode         On
        Docker_Mode_Flush   5
        Docker_Mode_Parser  container_firstline
        Parser              docker
        DB                  /var/fluent-bit/state/flb_dataplane_tail.db
        Mem_Buf_Limit       50MB
        Skip_Long_Lines     On
        Refresh_Interval    10
        Rotate_Wait         30
        Read_from_Head      Off

    [FILTER]
        Name                modify
        Match               dataplane.systemd.*
        Rename              _HOSTNAME                   hostname
        Rename              _SYSTEMD_UNIT               systemd_unit
        Rename              MESSAGE                     message
        Remove_regex        ^((?!hostname|systemd_unit|message).)*$

    [FILTER]
        Name                aws
        Match               dataplane.*
        imds_version        v1

    [OUTPUT]
        Name                cloudwatch_logs
        Match               dataplane.*
        region              ${REGION}
        log_group_name      /aws/containerinsights/${CLUSTER_NAME}/dataplane
        log_stream_prefix   ${APP_POD_NAMESPACE}-${APP_POD_NAME}-
        auto_create_group   true
        extra_user_agent    container-insights
    
    [INPUT]
        Name                tail
        Tag                 host.dmesg
        Path                /var/log/dmesg
        Parser              syslog
        DB                  /var/fluent-bit/state/flb_dmesg.db
        Mem_Buf_Limit       5MB
        Skip_Long_Lines     On
        Refresh_Interval    10
        Read_from_Head      Off

    [INPUT]
        Name                tail
        Tag                 host.messages
        Path                /var/log/messages
        Parser              syslog
        DB                  /var/fluent-bit/state/flb_messages.db
        Mem_Buf_Limit       5MB
        Skip_Long_Lines     On
        Refresh_Interval    10
        Read_from_Head      Off

    [INPUT]
        Name                tail
        Tag                 host.secure
        Path                /var/log/secure
        Parser              syslog
        DB                  /var/fluent-bit/state/flb_secure.db
        Mem_Buf_Limit       5MB
        Skip_Long_Lines     On
        Refresh_Interval    10
        Read_from_Head      Off

    [FILTER]
        Name                aws
        Match               host.*
        imds_version        v1

    [OUTPUT]
        Name                cloudwatch_logs
        Match               host.*
        region              ${REGION}
        log_group_name      /aws/containerinsights/${CLUSTER_NAME}/host
        log_stream_prefix   ${APP_NODE_NAME}.
        auto_create_group   true
        extra_user_agent    container-insights

  
  custom_parsers.conf: |
    [PARSER]
        Name                docker
        Format              json
        Time_Key            time
        Time_Format         %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ
    
    [PARSER]
        Name               cri
        Format             regex
        Regex              (?<log>(?<="log":")\S(?!\.).*?)(?<!\\)".*(?<stream>(?<="stream":").*?)".*(?<time>\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\w*).*(?=})
        Time_Key            time
        Time_Format         %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ
        Time_Keep           On
    [PARSER]
        Name                syslog
        Format              regex
        Regex               ^(?<time>[^ ]* {1,2}[^ ]* [^ ]*) (?<host>[^ ]*) (?<ident>[a-zA-Z0-9_\/\.\-]*)(?:\[(?<pid>[0-9]+)\])?(?:[^\:]*\:)? *(?<message>.*)$
        Time_Key            time
        Time_Format         %b %d %H:%M:%S

    [PARSER]
        Name                container_firstline
        Format              regex
        Regex               (?<log>(?<="log":")\S(?!\.).*?)(?<!\\)".*(?<stream>(?<="stream":").*?)".*(?<time>\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\w*).*(?=})
        Time_Key            time
        Time_Format         %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ

    [PARSER]
        Name                cwagent_firstline
        Format              regex
        Regex               (?<log>(?<="log":")\d{4}[\/-]\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{1,2}[ T]\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?!\.).*?)(?<!\\)".*(?<stream>(?<="stream":").*?)".*(?<time>\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\w*).*(?=})
        Time_Key            time
        Time_Format         %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ
```

Comment: have you made progress on this? i am facing a similar issue with using the multiline_parser alongside the docker parser

Comment: Same thing, multiline.parser set in `python,docker,cri` doesn't help, still every line is separate.

Comment: the same issue, I have been working on it for a few days already